# How i can get the members of a office 365 security group (none-mail enabled)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, powerapp

Inside Office 365 , i have security group without email address and I want to list its members. I found 2 actions:-

[image]

but I am not sure how I can filter the "List Groups" by name to get the group id and pass it to the second action "List group members". now both actions can get the security group, because when I hardcoded the group id it worked well, and the "list groups" action will get the related group. but not sure how I can filter the first action by group name to get the group id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the action `List groups` of `Office 365 Groups` you can use an OData filter to get a specific group (event security group without email). For example:

```
displayName eq 'sg-Engineering'
```

As the result will be an array (even if there is only one group with this name), you can use a `Apply to each` action and use the `List group members` action with the `Group Id` from the initial request:

```
items('Apply_to_each')?['id']
```

If you are sure there is only one group, you can skip the `Apply to each` and use the `[0]` index:

```
outputs('List_groups')?['body/value'][0]?['id']
```

Here's the cloud flow:

[image: workflow with foreach]

Or without the `Apply to each`:
[image: workflow index 0]

And the result:

[image: result]